# Smack Error not-authorized(401)

Tags: xmpp, smack

I'm working with smack to create a chat room for my web site but as I want to change a rooms configuration or its members, when I want to get i'ts current members or just doing any other modification, I get Error not-authorized(401)!I'm connected with an administrator account which is the owner of the room too!  by the way I can do all these jobs through a client with out any problem!
any body has any Idea How can I fix it?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the problem :) it was because I should have joined the room first and then I could manage it!
like this :

```
MultiUserChat room = new MultiUserChat(connection, roomId);
room.join("admin"); // missing line :)
Collection<Affiliate> currentMembers=room.getMembers();
```